# Can't find the name space for colorcoverter in MahApps.Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am new to C# programming so please bear with my inferior knowledge in it.I am creating a wpf application in visual studio 2015 and using MahApps.Metro NuGet package to design my gui but when i use 
"local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter" command in my xaml file, it returns an error "the type was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. I have included the xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls in my xaml controls and in code view "using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;" is included. still the error remains. Any solutions?

```
local:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter
```

Comment: Simple reason: There is no `ColorConverter` in `MahApps.Metro`, where did you defined your converter?

Comment: Sorry i got it now. It was a user defined function from a code i saw online. Thanks for the help @Fruchtzwerg